# Convert specific MS Access query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have MS Access query and try to convert to SQL Server query.

Please someone can help me.

```
UPDATE AppReferrals
SET AppReferrals.DeviceID = CLng(Val(Left(IIf([AppReferrals].[DeviceID] Like '0',[AppReferrals].[ActionID],[AppReferrals].[DeviceID]),9)));
```

Comment: "Help me" isn't a question. What were you attempts and why didn't they work?

Comment: This is query from MS Access  I try to convert it to SQL query. Thank you

Comment: Edit question to show attempt. What's wrong with using MS Access version? LIKE is useless without wildcard - might as well just use = sign.

Comment: Please cancel my question. Sorry for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good I think I'm very old

I worked with Visual basic in my first job 20 years ago

basically what you are doing is taking a value "first 9 digit" (DeviceID) and this is null the alternative (ActionID) and converting it to an Long value

using the following functions

1. [CLng](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions)
2. [Val](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function)
3. [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function)
4. [IIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function)
5. Like

[Example in visual basic net the function](https://rextester.com/FABK29686)